# Tool or Standard Procedure to add a different type of Visual Studio Project to an existing one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, webforms, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have an existing website coded in ASP.Net 4.0 **Webforms**, and would like to add an "**ASP.Net Dynamic Data Entities Web Application**" (project templates of VS2010 to my actual project):

[image: ASP.Net Dynamic Data Entities Web Application]

So my question is, what are the steps to "merge" the 2 projects or integrate the "ASP.Net Dynamic Data Entities Web Application" to my actual webforms.

I think I must merge my Global.asax.cs files and web.config file + move rest of the files. Is that correct ?

I already read that post (that may be outdated?):
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Thanks for your answers :)
(the original title of this post was: “ASP.Net Dynamic Data Entities Web Application” integration with an existing Webforms)

Answer (score 1):

I've read Scott Hanselman's article which you've provided in your question and yes the same technique still applies today, here are a few steps/considerations which should help you along the way:

1. When you create the new ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application make sure that it's the same .NET Framework version as your Web Forms project, to avoid version conflicts.
2. Remember to add a reference to all the required libraries that you've been using in the Web Forms project.
3. Now it's safe to copy all the necessary .aspx pages to the new site.
4. There is some automatically generated code inside the Global.asax of a Dynamic Data project which is used to configure ASP.NET routing, it may be useful later so instead of replacing it with your Global.asax use a tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/) to merge the two files.

Comment: Thanks Deni, but do you know if there is a Step by Step procedure ? It's crazy Microsoft never produced a tool for that purpose...

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tools.Like I said software like WinMerge can help you merge files but you still have to do some manual tweaking.